# SSIS - package deployment model deploy to MSDB

Tags: deployment, ssis, package

I'm using SQL 2016 and am creating SSIS packages.  Due to the environment, the SSIS packages must use the package deployment model and not the project deployment model.  Integration Service Catalogs will not be installed.

This link indicates using the legacy package deployment model, SSIS packages may be stored in the MSDB.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-ver15

I've googled for instructions on how to store legacy package model SSIS packages to the MSDB and can't seem to find any instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Create deployment utility
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/legacy-package-deployment-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15#create-a-deployment-utility

Then deploy with deployment utility (.SSISDeploymentManifest)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/legacy-package-deployment-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15#deploy-packages-by-using-the-deployment-utility